# SQL Query the same table twice

Tags: sql, alias

I have two tables, I need to query the same column in the 1st table twice, for both columns in the second table, and return the second data column from the 1st table.

So,

**Table1: Resources**

```
ID, URL

1, a.com

2, b.com

3, c.com
```

**Table2: Referrals**

```
SourceID, ReferralID

1, 1

1, 3

3, 1
```

**I need the result;**

```
SourceURL, ReferralURL

a.com, a.com

a.com, c.com

c.com, a.com
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, twice.

Comment: Does Referrals table allow `NULL` value ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the tables twice

```
    select r1.URL as SourceURL, r2.URL as ReferralURL 
    from Referrals r
    inner join Resources r1 on r.SourceID = r1.ID
    inner join Resource r2 on r.referalID = r2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join twice to get the result (first to get the source URL, and second to get the referral URL)

```
SELECT
    RES1.URL AS SourceURL
    ,RES2.URL AS ReferralURL
FROM Referrals REF
INNER JOIN Resources RES1
    ON REF.SourceID = RES1.ID
INNER JOIN Resources RES2
    ON REF.ReferralID = RES2.ID
```

Comment: Worked like a dream;  this was my query with the correct names;
It's to pull the all the referral urls for all Site Collections from a SharePoint 2007 instance, directly from the database


SELECT
    RES1.FullUrl AS SourceURL
    ,RES2.FullUrl AS ReferralURL
FROM ANLHit REF
INNER JOIN ANLResource RES1
    ON REF.ResourceId = RES1.ResourceId
INNER JOIN ANLResource RES2
    ON REF.ReferrerResourceId = RES2.ResourceId